# How to add variable length ending to SSRS textbox in tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix where the first column is a description and the 2nd column is a value. I would like the first column to contain: [description] followed by periods to the end of the column so that the report shows the following:

```
Description            Value
Item 1 ............... 3.00
Another Item ......... 5.00
Some other Item ...... 1.00
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, the description is built from an expression NOT a field in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve it you have to do the following:

Set textbox CanGrow to false and size your column to fit your largest string in one line. You should also fix the row heigh to display only the first row of data.

Concatenate your expression with a string of dots, containing as enough dots to cover your smallest string length

```
=Fields!s.Value  & "................................................"
```

[image]

[image]